# Inherit custom methods when merging arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, metaprogramming

I have some custom methods defined on instances of an array, for example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]

a.define_singleton_method(:foo) do
  "foo"
end

a.foo
# => "foo"
```

Is it possible to *pass / inherit / preserve* this custom methods, when the `a` array is added to another array (or any other array operation like uniq, intersection...) for example:

```
(a + b).foo
# undefined method `foo' for [1, 2, 3, 4]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

This makes sense because a new array is created. But I wonder if there is a method to preserve the custom methods on the `a` array on the newly created array.
Of course, I could pass every array through the same step where `define_singleton_method` is called, but this becomes very complicated in time and you could easily forget an array.

Comment: A "viral" method like this would make the code very difficult to understand. How do you know which arrays have #foo and which do not? Instead, consider [refining Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) to add your method to Array but only in your code. Alternatively write a class which [delegates to an Array](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/delegate-methods-in-ruby/).

Comment: thanks, never thought of refining my arrays, I'll try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* write a `ViralArray` subclass of `Array` which overrides every `Array` method to produce a new Array which includes your extra method.

```
class ViralArray < Array
  [:+, :*, :-].each { |method|
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      new_array = super(*args)
      new_array.define_singleton_method(:foo) do
        "foo"
      end
      new_array
    end
  }
end

my = ViralArray[1,2,3]
b = my + [4,5,6]
p b.foo    # "foo"
p b.class  # Array
```

This would obviously be tedious and prone to breakage.

But viral methods like this makes the code very difficult to understand. You'd never know which Arrays have #foo and which do not.

Instead, [`refine` Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). A refinement is like monkey patching, but in a limited scope.

Define a refinement of `Array` that adds `#foo`.

```
module FooArray
  refine Array do
    def foo
      "foo: #{object_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

And use it in code which expects Arrays with a `foo` method.

```
using FooArray

a = [1,2,3]
puts a.foo
```

All other code will be unaffected.